# How not to destroy container upon failure

Tags: molecule

Is there a way to have molecule **not** destroy the docker container that was created upon a failure?

I have the following scenario in `molecule.yml`:

```
scenario:
  name: default
  test_sequence:
    - create
    - converge
    - verify
```

One of the testinfra test is failing and I'd like to inspect the container after the failure (`docker exec -it xxxx /bin/bash`).

However, molecule keeps on cleaning up the container:

```
An error occurred during the test sequence action: 'verify'. Cleaning up.
--> Scenario: 'default'
--> Action: 'destroy'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `--destroy never` flag should be used (e.g. `molecule test --destroy never`).

Comment: You forgot to mark this answer as the solution to your question.